# Generate group of data based on sum of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to calculate the sum and total files.

here is my table

```
**FileId**          **FileSize(MB)**
    1                      5
    2                      4
    3                      1
    4                      6
    5                      8
    6                      1
    7                      7
    8                      2
```

Expected result

```
BatchNo         StartId          EndId        BatchSize
   1               1               3             10
   2               4               4              6
   3               5               6              9
   4               7               8              9
```

If File Size >= 10 then start new batch

also file count per batch is >= 10 then start new batch

StartId and EndId based on FileId

and BatchNo Is AutoIncrement

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Provide more details to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use recursive query like this

```
with rdata as
(
      select row_number() over (order by fileId) rn, * from data
), rcte as
(
  select 1 no, 1 gr, fileSize fileSizeSum , * 
  from rdata where fileid = 1
  union all
  select case when fileSizeSum + d.fileSize > 10 or r.no = 10 then 1 else r.no + 1 end gr,
         case when fileSizeSum + d.fileSize > 10 or r.no = 10 then r.gr + 1 else r.gr end gr,
         case when fileSizeSum + d.fileSize > 10 or r.no = 10 then d.fileSize else d.fileSize + fileSizeSum  end fileSizeSum, 
         d.*
  from rcte r
  join rdata d on r.rn + 1 = d.rn
)
select r.gr, 
       min(fileId), 
       max(fileId), 
       max(fileSizeSum)
from rcte r
group by r.gr
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6007f1d6e3287e658a815be90d958dc2)

Comment: if i don't have fileid in sequence then how can it's possible?

Comment: This is really brittle. If the values in fileId have a gap this whole process is broken. ROW_NUMBER might be a viable alternative.

Comment: @SeanLange I was too lazy for a more general solution, but I have updated it as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, with different approach:

```
INSERT INTO #batchdetails (FileID, FileSizeTotal, GroupID)
SELECT FileID, (
            SELECT SUM(filesize) FROM #filedetails f2
            WHERE f1.fileid >= f2.fileid ) AS FileSizeTotal,
    1+CONVERT(INT,(
            SELECT SUM(filesize) FROM #filedetails f2
            WHERE f1.fileid >= f2.fileid
    )/(@filesizepergroup+0.1)) AS GroupID
FROM #filedetails f1

SELECT DISTINCT
    BatchDetails.GroupID AS BatchNo,
    MIN(BatchDetails.FileID) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDetails.GroupID ORDER BY BatchDetails.GroupID) AS StartID,
    MAX(BatchDetails.FileID) OVER (PARTITION BY BatchDetails.GroupID ORDER BY BatchDetails.GroupID) AS EndID,
    BatchSizeGroup.BatchSize
FROM #batchdetails BatchDetails
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT GroupID, (GroupFileSizeTotal - LAG(GroupFileSizeTotal,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY GroupID)) AS BatchSize
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            GroupID, 
            MAX(FileSizeTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY GroupID) AS GroupFileSizeTotal
        FROM #batchdetails
        GROUP BY GroupID, FileSizeTotal
    )A
)BatchSizeGroup ON BatchDetails.GroupID = BatchSizeGroup.GroupID
GROUP BY BatchDetails.GroupID, BatchDetails.FileID, BatchSizeGroup.BatchSize
```

Demo is Here : [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62cf8627732e1497c82c0bade37fb946)